# Mass-assign protected attributes (Nested-form) Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-forms

I'm trying to create a nested form but i got this error when trying to assign the parameters. I read a bunch of similar posts but cant figure out the problem. What could be wrong?

`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: detalle_poliza`

My models:

poliza_contable.rb

```
class PolizaContable < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :detalle_polizas
accepts_nested_attributes_for :detalle_polizas
  attr_accessible :concepto_poliza, :estatus, :fecha_aplicacion, :fecha_poliza, :no_poliza, :tipo, :tota_de_cargos, :total_de_abonos
end
```

detalle_poliza.rb

```
class DetallePoliza < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :cuenta_contable
      belongs_to :poliza_contable 
      attr_accessible :abono, :cargo,:cuenta_contable_id, :poliza_contable_id, :user_id, :id, :updated_at, :created_at
    end
```

My form:

```
<%= form_for @poliza_contable, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
## OTHER FIELDS

<%= f.fields_for :detalle_poliza_attributes  do |builder| %>
   <% render :partial => "detalle_polizas/form", :locals => { :f => builder } %>
   <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Rendered form:

```
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :cargo, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :cargo, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :abono, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :abono, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :poliza_contable_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :poliza_contable_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :cuenta_contable_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :cuenta_contable_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :user_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :user_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Request Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"mI23Nnj4oPX+IW3mCvvIV7Auij+pjX/a7bl/HsudEW8=",
 "poliza_contable"=>{"tipo"=>"Diario",
 "concepto_poliza"=>"",
 "fecha_poliza"=>"2012-06-25",
 "detalle_poliza"=>{"cargo"=>"34",
 "abono"=>"34",
 "poliza_contable_id"=>"34",
 "cuenta_contable_id"=>"34",
 "user_id"=>"1"}}
 "commit"=>"Create Poliza contable"}`
```

I'll appreciate any comment to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

With according to [railscast 196 Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) you need to allow DetallePoliza attributes to be saved with parent. To achieve this goal just add **attr_accessible :detalle_polizas_attributes** to PolizaContable model:

poliza_contable.rb

```
class PolizaContable < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :detalle_polizas
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :detalle_polizas
  attr_accessible :concepto_poliza, :estatus, :fecha_aplicacion, :fecha_poliza, :no_poliza, :tipo, :tota_de_cargos, :total_de_abonos, :detalle_polizas_attributes
end
```

Comment: I already add it but still getting the error. Thanks for your review! But i still missing something else i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just making some research, finally found the [nestes_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Its a very straight forward implementation!

Hope it helps someone.